# ansible playbook copy file to docker container

Tags: file, docker, ansible, copy

I want copy a file to docker container using ansible playbook.
How can i do that ?

```
- name: kapacitor conf
  template: src=/home/debian/roles/tick_install/files/kapacitor.conf  dest=/etc/kapacitor/kapaci
```

```
my docker container = tick_kapacitor
```

Comment: Can you use the [`docker_container` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html)’s `volumes` setting to inject the file instead?  That’d be a more typical Docker setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using a plain Docker container without an orchestrated solution (such as Kubernetes or Swarm). If your container is already running, that will depend:

**Without volume mounted**

If you want to copy the file into an existing container which does not have a volume mounted where you want your file to be copied, I see no other way but running a `docker cp` command via `shell` or `command`, for example:

```
- name: Copy file into existing container at /path/in/the/container/kapaci
  shell: docker cp /etc/kapacitor/kapaci tick_kapacitor:/path/in/the/container/kapaci
```

**With a volume mounted in the container**

If you already have a volume mounted from the machine into the container, you can copy the file directly at the machine mount point. For example, if the container has a volume mounted from `/var/myapp/data` to `/path/in/the/container`, you can use `template` to copy the file directly into the container with its mounted volume:

```
name: kapacitor conf 
template: 
  src: /home/debian/roles/tick_install/files/kapacitor.conf
  dest: /var/myapp/data/kapacitor.conf
  # will be available in container at /path/in/the/container
```

## Running a new container

If you want to runner a new container, you can use the [`docker_container`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html) module or run a command (`docker run`, `docker-compose up...`...) which will run your container and then copy the file into it using one of the previously mentionned solution.